# dynamic calling/init a function or variable

Tags: php

Just of my curiousity I have a class that has

```
class someCLass {

  var $_var1 = '';
  var $_var2 = '';

  public function _set(){}

  public function _get(){}

  public function _put(){}

}
```

Is it possible to call this function dynamically. For example:

```
public function insomefunc(){

    $key_sample = 'set';

    $result = $this->_$keysample(); //call dynamically a function which should be _set()

}
```

the same way for a variable

```
public function insomefunc(){

    $var_sample = 'var1';

    $this->_$varsample = 'jackpot' //assign

}
```

Want to know answers for enlightment. Thank you

Comment: You want to run this outside of this class or inside ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran inside in the class

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add the "_" in your string:

```
public function insomefunc(){

    $key_sample = 'set';

    $result = $this->{'_'.$keysample}(); //call dynamically a function which should be _set()

}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this..

```
<?php
class someCLass
{

    var $_var1 = '';
    var $_var2 = '';

    public function set()
    {
        echo "I am set";
    }

    public function get()
    {
    }

    public function put()
    {
    }

    public function runset()
    {
        $key_sample = 'set';
        $this->$key_sample();
    }

}

$a = new someCLass();
$a->runset();
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
I am set
```